# Matching/filtering directly on an aggregate of a field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a MongoDb aggregation pipeline, I often encounter wanting to filter on an operation of a member field (i.e. size of a list). Is it possible doing this in one operation, rather than projecting a variable first, and then matching?

This is what I usually do:

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "vector_size": { "$size": "$VectorField" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "vector_size": { "$gte": 7 }
    }
  }
]
```

I would prefer a one-off, something like:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "VectorField": { "$size": { "$gte": 7 } }
    }
  }
]
```

But for that operation `$size` expects an integer, and not another operation.
It it possible?

Comment: Try this `[{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$gte": [{ "$size": "$VectorField" }, 7] }} }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` in `one condition`

```
db.getCollection('your-collection').find( {"$expr":{
   "$gte":[
     {"$size":'$VectorField'},
     7
   ]
 }})
```

Note: Tested in `3.6.5` on `mongo GUI`